# How can I filter one list with respect to another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently working with LINQ and a custom object and honestly I am a bit stuck. I have a custom class which represents a person. It looks like this:

```
private class Person
{
    private String Name;
    private String Firstname;

}
```

Now imagine the following situation: I have two arrays of `Person` (`Person1` and `Person2`). I want to get a list of those which have the same (in the list 2) Name but doesn't exist in the list 1 (for the other properties).

Example :

```
List<Person> Person1=new List<Person>(){new Person(){Name="Marley", Firstname="Bob"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Smith", Firstname="David"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Smith", Firstname="Thomas"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Flint", Firstname="John"}};

List<Person> Person2=new List<Person>(){new Person(){Name="Marley", Firstname="Bob"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Smith", Firstname="David"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Smith", Firstname="Thomas"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Smith", Firstname="Sandy"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Smith", Firstname="Catherine"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Flint", Firstname="John"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Simons", Firstname="Paul"},
                                    new Person(){Name="Flint", Firstname="Rachel"}};
```

In SQL the query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person1 
WHERE Person1.NAME IN (SELECT Person2.Name FROM Person2
                       WHERE Person2.Name=Person1.Name 
                       AND Person1.Firstname<>Person2.Firstname)
```

The result would be Sandy/Catherine Smith and Rachel Flint (NOT Paul Simons)

How could I do that in Linq ?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?  What problems are you having with your attempted solutions?  What research have you done into how to perform these operations in LINQ and in what way did they fail to solve your problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! To get the best help here, you need to add into the question what you have tested and how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want all with the "same firstname but not the same name" but your sql query looks for all with the same *name but a different firstname*.

If want all persons from `Person1` which are also in `Person2`(according to the `Name`) but which `FirstName` is different:

```
var query = Person1
    .Where(p => Person2
        .Any(p2 => p2.Name == p.Name && p2.Firstname != p.Firstname));
```

If you want a list use `query.ToList()`, if you want an array use `query.ToArray()`.

If you instead want all from `Person2`:

```
var query = Person2
        .Where(p2 => Person1
            .Any(p1 => p2.Name == p1.Name && p2.Firstname != p1.Firstname));
```

Comment: have you checked the results of this?

Comment: @Jonesy: i have looked at the requirement. Do you have some   reservations? It's easy to change if OP wants to find all persons where the `FirstName` equals but the `Name` is different.

Comment: running this against his test data I get `David Smith`, `Thomas Smith`, and `John Flint`

Comment: @Jonesy: yes, because all those are also in the second list with a different `FirstName`. Bob Marley is also in the second list but with the same Name + FirstName. If you look at his sql query you see that he uses `SELECT * FROM Person1 `.  Sandy/Catherine Smith  are not in `Person1` but `Person2`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then.  OP's expected output is certainly different, but the whole question is really a tossup

Comment: The code didn't help I only want the results from the second list which have some properties (not all) equals to the first ( in this case the name )

Comment: @TinyDev: try this approach which still does not yield the result result. Are you sure that it's the correct result?